# Store lights in an array as objects

Tags: object, shader, processing

Is it possible to store a number of lights, say pointLights, into an array? Processing treats them as built in methods, so which is the way to cast them as objects?

Example:

```java
 for (int i = 0; i < nLight; i++) {

        pointLight((int)(rnd.nextDouble() *255), (int)(rnd.nextDouble() *255), (int)(rnd.nextDouble() *255), (int)(rnd.nextDouble() *1000-1000),(int)(rnd.nextDouble() *1000-1000),(int)(rnd.nextDouble() *1000-1000));

        lights.add(light);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that encapsulates all of the information you need to draw a light. Something like this:

```java
class Light{
   float v1;
   float v2;
   float v3;
   float x;
   float y;
   float z;

   public Light(float v1, float v2, float v3, float x, float y, float z){
      this.v1 = v1;
      this.v2 = v2;
      this.v3 = v3;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.z = z;
   }

   public void draw(){
      pointLight(v1, v2, v3, x, y, z);
   }
}
```

Then to use that class, you'd simply create an `ArrayList` of `Light` instances and then iterate over those instances to draw the lights:

```java
ArrayList<Light> lights = new ArrayList<Light>();

void setup(){

   size(1000, 1000);

   for (int i = 0; i < nLight; i++) {
      lights.add(new Light(random(255), random(255), random(255), random(-1000, 1000), random(-1000, 1000), random(-1000, 1000)));
   }
}

void draw(){
   background(0);

   for(Light light : lights){
      light.draw();
   }
}
```